# What's the proper word for this type of 'porridge'?

Tags: word-request, image-identification

[image: rice]

What's called in English for this type of Chinese food? It's made of rice and water. Refer to the picture.

Comment: The dish is not common (at least in the UK), and would probably only be found in Chinese restaurants and the Chinese community. *Rice porridge* (or *porage*), and *rice congée* (if you want to be posh) sound OK (and Google knows about them). Connoisseurs of Chinese cuisine would probably know it by its Chinese name. I'm afraid I just order sweet and sour chicken, and egg-fried rice. I would avoid *rice gruel*. Gruel has negative connotations, and was a dish that only the poorest of people would eat (see Charles Dickens: *Oliver Twist*).

Comment: Are you looking for a term that would be understood by most native English speakers?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, yes, or commonly used among most native English speakers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "proper" term is the Chinese name, **congee**.  It's a perfectly acceptable (if not widely known) *borrowed* food term, like *sushi* or *spanokopita* or *falafel* or *borscht* or *soufflé* or (the ironically named) [*chop suey*](https://www.thespruce.com/history-of-chop-suey-694582).

> **[Congee](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/congee)** (n): (in Chinese cooking) broth or porridge made from rice.

"Rice porridge" would also be fine.